# Function application over collections with F-bounded types

Tags: scala, polymorphism, f-bounded-polymorphism

I've been trying to learn more Scala and ran into [this interesting article](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) discussing F-bounded types. I was particularly interested in the final discussion regarding working with collections of values with such types.

A simple example follows:

```
abstract class AbsClass[A <: AbsClass[_]] {
  this: A =>
  def me: A = this
}

def me2[A <: AbsClass[A]](a: A): A = a

case class C1(v: Int) extends AbsClass[C1] 
case class C2(v: Int) extends AbsClass[C2]
```

As shown in the blog post, we can use an existential quantifier to allow us to call `me2` over a list of `C1` and `C2`

```
scala> List[A forSome {type A <: AbsClass[A] }](C1(1), C2(2)).map(me2(_))
res2: List[A forSome { type A <: AbsClass[A] }] = List(C1(1), C2(2))
```

Now, I've been trying a couple of variations on the type for the list,
and I was hoping someone with more experience might point out some of the subtlety
that I am missing.

The following works as I expected it to

```
scala> val l2  =  List[A forSome {type A <: AbsClass[A] }](C1(1), C2(2))
l2: List[A forSome { type A <: AbsClass[A] }] = List(C1(1), C2(2))

scala> l2.map(_.me)
res4: List[A forSome { type A <: AbsClass[A] }] = List(C1(1), C2(2))
```

I can also call `_.me` and denote the list as containing instances of `AbsClass[A] forSome {type A}`, as in

```
scala> val l: List[AbsClass[_]] = List(C1(1), C2(2)).map(_.me)
l: List[AbsClass[_]] = List(C1(1), C2(2))
```

But when I try to apply the same map to `l` again, I lose type information and 
am stuck with a `List[Any]`. Is there a way to maintain the type here?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the underscore is a type bound.

```
val l: List[AbsClass[_]] = List(C1(1), C2(2)).map(_.me)

val ll: List[AbsClass[_ >: Nothing <: Any]] = List(C1(1), C2(2)).map(_.me)
```

These two things are the same. underscore will crush either to the lower bound of Nothing or to the upper bound of Any.

For more information on how existential types work, see: https://youtu.be/NFnsFda82Yo